# using openai gym(blackjack) to make ai

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm using openai gym to make an AI for blackjack.

but I'm not good at python and gym so idk how to complete the code.

I've been trying to write a simple code to make an AI using Q-learning.

but I am not familiar with open ai gym and python enough.

I don't know how to check a size of state(env.observation_space.n doesn't work.. only env.action_space.n show me its '2')
and my code is kinda copy of other examples of gym game(frozenlake)

help me out to complete this simple code so that I can improve this like DQN by myself.

```
import gym
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

env=gym.make('Blackjack-v0')

Q=np.zeros([400,env.action_space.n])

num_episodes=10000
dis=0.99
rList=[]

for i in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    rALL = 0
    done = False

    while not done: 
        action=np.argmax(Q[state,:]+np.random.randn(1
        ,env.action_space.n)/(i+1))


        new_state,reward,done,_=env.step(action)

        Q[state, action] = reward + dis * np.max(Q[new_state, :])
        print(rList)
        rALL += reward
        state = new_state

    rList.append(rALL)\


print(Q)
```

I wanna see that reward list(rList) keeps going up(if my algorithm works)

and also want to know how to use gym module well.

Comment: 1.i want to know how environment works. like how can i get the info of env by coding 2.wanna ask people if my algorithm is ok as Q-learning. 3.is there any method to make this game visualize?

Comment: and when i run this code, it seems like all episodes havent been done(loop doesnt work perfectly)

Comment: fix some grammar

Answer (score 0):

**I will update this response as I understand what you want exacty**

- For your first question in comment, you can get the number of actions by using `env.observation_space.n` and their meaning by `env.unwrapped.get_action_meanings()` if you use the latest version of `gym`.
- For your Third question, you can visualize the game by using `env.render()`.

Here is a minimal working exemple that renders the game with python3 and latest version of gym version '0.10.9' (you can get your gym version by `gym.__version__`):

```py
import time
import gym

# Create a breakout environment
env = gym.make('SpaceInvaders-v4')

# Reset it, returns the starting frame
frame = env.reset()

# Render
env.render()

is_done = False

while not is_done:
    # Perform a random action, returns the new frame, reward and whether the game is over
    frame, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(env.action_space.sample())
    # Render
    env.render()

    time.sleep(0.01)
    if is_done:
        env.close()
        break
```